# What was the first vinyl record ever pressed?

Tags: history, vinyl, record

I am wondering about, what was the first vinyl record ever pressed.
I am not interested in the first record ever (for example shellac), only the first vinyl record.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [The Record Collectors Guild](https://web.archive.org/web/20180916105832/http://www.recordcollectorsguild.org/modules.php?op=modload&name=sections&file=index&req=viewarticle&artid=44&page=1):

> In 1930, **RCA Victor** launched the first commercially-available vinyl
> long-playing record, marketed as "Program Transcription" discs. These
> revolutionary discs were designed for playback at 33⅓ rpm and pressed
> on a 12" diameter flexible plastic disc. In **Roland Gelatt**'s book ***The
> Fabulous Phonograph***, the author notes that RCA Victor's early
> introduction of a long-play disc was a commercial failure for several
> reasons including the lack of affordable, reliable consumer playback
> equipment and consumer wariness during the Great Depression.

The article also links to [this webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20181019115719/http://ronpenndorf.com/journalofrecordedmusic5.html), which explains:

> Thus, the 1930 RCA Victor Catalogue introduced their LP record, the
> 'Program Transcription.' This new kind of record was RCA's hope for
> restoring their market. By 1930, radio and the depression had reduced
> RCA's and all record companies' sales. The 'Program Transcription' was
> 12" in diameter, revolved at 33-1/3 RPM, had fine grooves (.0045 inch)
> that were closely spaced, and was made of **a flexible plastic called
> 'Victrolac.'** It carried up to 'three times' the playing time of a 12"
> 78, had quiet surfaces, and was to be played with a 1.5 mil RCA
> Chromium Orange Needle.

If you search for Victrolac, which seems to be somewhat synonymous of vinyl, you'll encounter [things like this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140201000428/https://78records.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/the-first-commercial-lps-rca-victor-program-transcriptions-1931/).

Comment: The most recent upvote caused this answer to get an award, which caused me to look at it (since I couldn't even remember writing it), and in checking it I discovered that all three links have now sadly become defunkt. Thankfully the Wayback Machine had indexed all three, and I could replace them with links to their backups.